# Interact with USB storage device from web page directly or using communication to native applications

Tags: usb, storage, native, html, platform-independent

I already had an Java application that is downloaded as part of java applets from the web page, that can interact with the USB Storage device where it need to save and retrieve data from the device.

Since the chrome has stopped supporting out of sandbox running applets, I need to develop some new technique to interact with the USB Storage Device from my web page. My application architect does not want to achieve same using JNLP which is one options that I have learnt by reading some articles.

Now I would like you peoples to help me on build some applications, so that I can use the same in my webpage to access USB storage device(Pen drive) independent of OS (Operating System) and Independent of Browser(Cross browser support-mostly should work on IE, firefox , chrome and safari).

I am ok with application build on native (OS dependent), but should be there a way to communicate with that application from any browsers installed over that machine.